# Fingerprint can't be blank / Contents Invalid public key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, rsa

I'm having trouble curling a backup from Heroku.  I'm trying to use `heroku add:keys` but every time I do I get the error:

`Fingerprint can't be blank / Contents Invalid public key`

I'm thinking that I'm getting this error because I created the RSA I already had for GitHub and used a different email, but I have no idea.  Can anyone offer solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just adding a new RSA and things worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Just type

```
ssh-keygen
```

to generate a new RSA key.